# Would there be any code requirements in the way of leaving roof trusses and attic above a habitable room exposed for an industrial look.?

Tags: ceiling, code-compliance, attic, joists, interior

I am working on remodelling my house and want exposed ceilings in some rooms. The roof was recently replaced and r-35 insulation was installed above my roof decking. All interior walls were framed and will be drywalled up to the roofline. All the electrical is done and wired into conduits and has passed inspection. HVAC will have exposed spiral duct in some regions as needed. After everything is complete, I plan to paint everything (trusses, conduits, ductwork and ceiling) black except for the walls.

My plan is to paint trusses like in the top picture to achieve a design similar to the bottom picture. If all electrical has passed inspection, would there be any code requirements in the way for exposed roof trusses/rafters/joists in a finished room (living room, bedroom, etc)?

[image: What my ceiling looks like before painted]
[image: Finished exposed ceiling, after painted]

Comment: Whose code? So many codes, so many options… start by country.

Comment: Do you mean the code of Idiotistan, which requires exclusively square angles in living spaces?

Comment: Would imagine there might be fire codes instead of building codes about leaving them open/visible.  Steel/metal material probably less fire code to cover/block.

Comment: Where in the world are you?

Comment: @crip659 -- AFAICT, the IRC permits exposed roof-ceiling structural members.  my main concern for the OP would be that there's no ceiling diaphragm here, but that'd require a structural engineer's evaluation

Comment: I am from the USA. So would this design be allowed in the USA